# Infinite Scroll with working History Back on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've developed an infinite scroll for my e-commerce website. Everything works great, but I have 100+ products on some pages, and it's really annoying for the customers, that they have to start over, once they hit the back button (when they're previewing products).

I tried the `replaceState` function - I've saved a `jSON` string after the `#` in the url that saves the current position from top, and the `offset`, that I was going to use after customer's returning. It was terrible. On the latest version of iOS Chrome and Safari didn't worked at all, on some Windows 7 browsers it was lagging as hell.

Anyway, has anyone tried the `History.js`? Is it the same pain in the a**? What about other methods? I was thinking about setting the `offset` as cookie, but will the browser wait until the AJAX loads all of the products?

Here's also my current code (AJAX only, no history functions):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // LazyLoad
        function LazyLoad(collection, main, category, sort, offset, limit) {
            window.ajax = false;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://daytona.bg/includes/ajax.php",
                data: "collection=" + collection + "&main=" + main + "&category=" + category + "&sort=" + sort + "&offset=" + offset + "&limit=" + limit,
                success: function(result) {
                    $.each(JSON.parse(result), function(key, value) {
                        $("#products").append('<div id="products-item">PRODUCT STUFF HERE</div>');
                    });

                    window.ajax = true;
                }
            });
        }

        // Globals
        window.ajax = true;

        // Variables
        var collection = 'fall-winter';
        var main = 'women';
        var category = 'jackets';
        var sort = 'new';
        var offset = 0;
        var limit = 12;

        // OnLoad
        $(window).load(function() {
            LazyLoad(collection, main, category, sort, offset, limit);
        });

        // OnScroll
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 900) && window.ajax == true) {
                LazyLoad(collection, main, category, sort, offset +=12, limit);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

Here's cool example from HM:

http://www2.hm.com/bg_bg/jeni/pazaruvane-po-vid-produkt/jaketa-i-palta.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind supporting I.E8 and above you can use sessionStorage (unlike localStorage, this cache will stick with the TAB or session, for as long as its alive, once closed by the user it gets cleared by itself)

[Mozilla API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) offers some examples:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

use this to store the current page or container div's HTML (AND the scrollbar horizontal position) upon navigating *away* from the page.

then, upon going 'back', check if the key contains any data in it, if it does, i'd use jquery to load the content into the div.

```
$selector.load(sessionStorage.getItem('your-unique-key')).stop().hide().fadeIn();
```

then use jquery to scroll to the position, possibliy save it in under another key.

```
$.scrollTo(sessionStorage.getItem('my-last-scroll-bar-position'));
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the AJAX results using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and add a load handler to your script that first builds the results from localStorage before making any AJAX requests.